# Using "prop" namespace in camel blueprint to resolve a property

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

When i am trying to resolve few properties as xs:int values using prop namespace(http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder) as explained in camel documentation (http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html) i am facing below issue where bundle goes to "**GRACEPERIOD**" when trying to resolve the namespace.

```
09:08:35,325 | DEBUG | e-1.1.0-thread-1 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 15 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.0.1.redhat-60024 | Running blueprint container for bundle MyBundle
in state WaitForNamespaceHandlers
09:08:35,325 | INFO  | e-1.1.0-thread-1 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 15 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.0.1.redhat-60024 | Bundle MyBundle is waiting for namespace hand
lers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder]
09:08:35,325 | DEBUG | e-1.1.0-thread-1 | BlueprintEventDispatcher         | 15 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.0.1.redhat-60024 | Sending blueprint container event BlueprintEvent[type=GRACE_
PERIOD, dependencies=[(&(objectClass=org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler)(osgi.service.blueprint.namespace=http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder))]] for bundle MyBundle
09:08:35,325 | DEBUG | nt Dispatcher: 1 | BlueprintListener                | 48 - org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi - 2.3.0.redhat-60024 | Blueprint app state changed to GracePeriod for bundle 284
```

Below is the blueprint xml i am using

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
   http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


<cm:property-placeholder id="id2" persistent-id="protectedproperties"
           placeholder-prefix="$(" placeholder-suffix=")"/> 
<cm:property-placeholder id="id1" persistent-id="instance" placeholder-prefix="${" placeholder-suffix="}"/>

<camel:camelContext id="blueprintContext" trace="false"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" streamCache="true"
    handleFault="false" useBreadcrumb="false" useBlueprintPropertyResolver="false">

    <!-- Disable jmxAgent to improve performance. This needs to be enabled 
        only when the flow needs to be seen via hawtio -->
    <camel:jmxAgent disabled="true" />


    <camel:threadPoolProfile
        id="changedProfile"
        defaultProfile="true"
        prop:poolSize="camel.thread.poolSize"
        prop:maxPoolSize="camel.thread.maxPoolSize"
        prop:maxQueueSize="camel.thread.maxQueueSize"/>

</camel:camelContext>
```

Please help me find how to resolve the namespace in blueprint.

> Versions used:
>
> > Camel Core : 2.10.0.redhat-60024
> >
> > Camel Blueprint : 2.10.0.redhat-60024
> >
> > Jboss Fuse : 6.0.0.redhat-024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's never going to work in your setup.

The page you linked [using propertyplaceholder](http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html) clearly states:

> Using Property Placeholders for Any Kind of Attribute in the XML DSL
>   Available as of Camel 2.7
>   If you use OSGi Blueprint then this only works from **2.11.1** or **2.10.5** on.

Your old version of JBoss Fuse provides **2.10.0**

You should upgrade to the latest JBoss Fuse.
At this time the latest version is 6.3.0 with Camel 2.17.0